# add-in for office 2013 compatible with office 2010?

Tags: outlook, ms-office

I have been thinking of developing an add-in in office 2013 but the thought hit me..is it backwords compatible with older versions 2010? 2007? ive read a few articles and even some answers that were given here but none of the directly answerd my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, you should target your addin at the lowest version of Outlook (2007?).
If there are any version specific features that you want to use, you can use Application.Version to branch your code.